# "netcoreapp1.0" is an unsupported framework. - Asp.Net Core Music Store

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm just trying out asp.net core for the first time.  Opening up the newly updated [music store app](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) but I can't get it to build Nuget tells me:

```
Errors in C:\development\MusicStore\test\E2ETests\project.json
    "netcoreapp1.0" is an unsupported framework.
```

How can I get the .net framework reference to restore?

Comment: are you using Visual Studio ?

Comment: yes. VS 2015 RC1.  All updates I can find are installed.

Comment: try `master` branch, `dev` branch not yet compatible for VS 2015

Comment: You have to try the rc1-final tag. the master/dev ones are based on the nightly builds. Also it has nothing to do with your visual studio version. Its related to the tooling (Dnx for rc1-final and dotnet-cli for latest nightlies). https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/1.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 9):

RC2 was released yesterday, and now you can. You need:

1. Install tooling for VS2015 from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481 (link from [step 1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows))
2. Upgrade NuGet (VS Extensions) - 3.4.3.855 (auto-updated) works for me, but version 3.5.0 (beta) is recommended [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) (second [link](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.5.0-beta/NuGet.Tools.vsix) in step 1).
3. Edit your `global.json` file - update `version` property to `1.0.0-preview1-002702` (details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/16/announcing-updated-web-development-tools-for-asp-net-core-rc2/))

Comment: Thanks for this, missed the global.json update in my case.  Also I had to execute `dotnet restore` for intellisense to stop giving me the error.

Comment: @Dmitry Where can I get NuGet (VS Extensions) to 3.5.0 + from? 'Extensions and Updates' in VS 2015 is only showing 3.4.3.855. I've installed 'DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe' already.  Thanks.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows, step 1 - link to https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.5.0-beta/NuGet.Tools.vsix . But my VS currently have 3.4.3.855 (auto-updated) and everything works... May be 3.5.0 is not obligatory... Updated my answer. Did you updated your `global.json` file?

Comment: Making the change to global.json fixed the issue for me. (I had updates already installed)

Answer (score 0):

In `ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM` `Tools Preview 2` the version needs to be:

```
"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
```

(Run `dotnet --version` to make sure) Then don't forget to run:

```
dotnet restore
```

in your `Package Manager Console`, `Command Prompt` or `Git Bash`