# Getting “netcoreapp1.0” is an unsupported framework during Docker build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-1.0

I am creating a ASP.net Core application and I am trying to do a docker build for this application. I am getting following error -

[image]

My project.json file is as follows -

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

and my global.json file is as -

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

I am following dockerfile for docker build -

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final

ADD . /project

WORKDIR /project

RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "web", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]
```

Please suggest a solution for this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["netcoreapp1.0" is an unsupported framework. - Asp.Net Core Music Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181602/netcoreapp1-0-is-an-unsupported-framework-asp-net-core-music-store). You should also probably upgrade from *preview2* to the official release of 1.0 or 1.1

Comment: I tried to use the different versions but the problem is not resolved.